# How can I ensure that my Python version is updated after installing version 3.11 using Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, path, pythonpath

I've just installed Python version 3.11 (I also moved versions 3.8 and 3.9 to the trash from my Applications folder).

I can see it in the following:

```
$ myname@name-MBP miniconda3 % ls /usr/local/bin/py*
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3           /usr/local/bin/python3-intel64
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11        /usr/local/bin/python3.11
/usr/local/bin/python3          /usr/local/bin/python3.11-config
/usr/local/bin/python3-config       /usr/local/bin/python3.11-intel64
```

(Any additional recommendations on whether I need to clean things up would be much appreciated.)

Checking `python3 --version` still displays `Python 3.8.13`.

**First attempt to solve**

Initially I tried installing it from the command line using `homebrew` and specifying the version:

`brew install python@3.11`

I also tried using `conda`, but neither of these worked.

**Second attempt to solve**

My initial thought was to check my PATH (I think this is how Python decides which version to use, but please correct me if I'm wrong).

This still only contained version 8 paths:

```
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python38.zip
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Users/myname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

So I added the Python3.11 path to it using

```
PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11/:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH
```

Now it includes the v3.11 path when I print out `sys.path`:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.11
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11
/Users/myname/miniconda3
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python38.zip
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Users/myname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Users/myname/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages
```

But the `python3 --version` output is still unchanged.

**Questions**

I'm nervous to keep playing around with the contents of my path and entering random command line executions to try to solve this because I really have no clue what I'm doing.

What's happening here?

How can I get the output of `python3 --version` to be 3.11?

Comment: This should be an easy fix, I need only a few key pieces of information. Can you share the output of `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`.

Comment: you have multiple python versions if you run this cmd you can get your desired version `python3.11 --version`. it's better to use `pyenv` if you need multiple versions.

Comment: @Moulick I've put ** where the new lines should be to make it clearer

/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/bin **
/Users/oliverprice/miniconda3/condabin **
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin **
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin **
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin **
/usr/local/bin 
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Library/TeX/texbin~/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11~/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing to understand is setting the variable `PYTHONPATH` will not affect which version of python is executed by the shell. The shell (bash/zsh) only knows to scan the paths in the `PATH` env var to figure out all the executables.

### Now there are two ways to solve this.

#### 1. Using the `python@3.11` from homebrew.

There are several downsides to using this method. Currently, the default python3 by brew is `3.10.x`. Whenever you will install any cask or formula that depends on python@3, it'll invariably install the python@3 formula aka 3.10.x. Installing `python3` will make brew symlink 3.10.x into `/opt/homebrew/bin`.

[image: python3 symlinks]

Python 3.11.x can be used by installing `python@3.11` and invoking `python3.11`. This should drop you into the Python 3.11 interpreter. Append all python executable names with the version like `pip` will be `pip3.11`

[image: python and pip 3.11]

**Trying to force 3.11 over 3.10 links will be complicated and cause instability. It'll only cause frustration during development.**

#### 2. Using VirtualEnvs

Your best bet for the most stable and no-headache approach to python is to create virtual envs using either `venv` or [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-in-macos). use [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#installing-with-homebrew-for-macos-users) for max ease of use.

One limitation of `venv` is that it'll create a virtualenv of the same version that invoked it. Aka if you do `brew install python@3 && python3 -m venv <folder>`, it'll create virtualenv of python3. For 3.11 you'll have to `brew install python@3.11 && python3.11 -m venv <folder>`. Pyenv on the other hand can install any version of python.

Go through https://www.dataquest.io/blog/a-complete-guide-to-python-virtual-environments/ and https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv to understand and learn more.